# ways around broken `TextInput` component in react-native

Tags: react-native

As far as I can tell by default the react native text input component has some inconsistencies on iOS from the normal text input when using it in a controlled way. The examples I've found so far:

1. the "period shortcut" (pressing two spaces to get a period in text) does not work.
2. typing a special character and then space does not switch the keyboard back to its normal mode
3. spelling errors do not have a red underline
4. often text replacement shortcuts don't work

I'm trying to get around this in the short term and so far the only thing I've found that works is using a multiline input. At this point I'm trying to "hack" the multiline input to work like a singleline, but figured it was also worth reaching out to see if anyone else has a better solution.

Comment: did you find any solution regarding this issue?

Comment: as mentioned above I'm still forcing a multiline input to act as a single line input. It isn't ideal, but its better than anything I've found so far.